# Why are the Ember Data REST Adapter and LS Adapter structured differently? One returns, one doesn't

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been studying the findAll() function of Ember Data Local Storage Adapter and REST Adapter. I have thought that adapters should follow the same structure, but it doesn't seem that is true.

How come the [REST Adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/78068419da2209ea050206548d0f5bb69670236b/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L349) has a return but the [LS Adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L107-L116) doesn't have a return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest Adapter didn't have that change too, until [this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/934/files#L2L261) PR.

I think that LS Adapter doesn't return the promisse because it outdated, at the moment the last update in [this](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L107-L116) file was 7 months ago.

I recommend you to return the promisse to have the advanage of use.

```
App.User.find().then( ... )
```